# fetch data kubernetes cluster [ibm cloud]

Tags: express, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

i implemented a application with mongodb and nodejs using docker. now i want deploy my application into ibm cloud. im using a kubernetes cluster. my application is running, and my mongodb also, now i want to fetch data to my application. i need to access this with my location adress, i searched in my kubernetes services and found this:

```
cloudchat-lab1

172.21.101.196

cloudchat-lab1:4000 TCP
cloudchat-lab1:30286 TCP
```

the part of register.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CloudChat-Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
<section>

  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <br>
  <br>

<p>
  username:<input id="username">
  <br>
  <br>
  password:<input id="password" type="password">
  <br>
  <br>
  password-re:<input id="password2" type="password">
</p>
<br>

<button id="submitButtonLogin" onclick="onClick_()">Submit</button>

<br>
<br>
<button class="button" onclick="window.location.href='/'">Login-Page</button>

    </section>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  <script>

    async function onClick_(){
        const val = document.getElementById('username').value
  
        const val2 = document.getElementById('password').value
 
        const val3 = document.getElementById('password2').value


        console.log("ich")

        if(val.length>=6){
          if(val2.length>=6){

           if(val2!=val){
            if(val2.value==val3.value){
              

              //const response = await fetch('https://localhost:4000/users/new', {
           const response = await fetch('https://172.21.101.196:4000/users/new', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username:val,
              password:val2})
  
            });

            //if response contains 'success' the user will be href to loginpage
            const content = await response.json();

            if(content.message=='success'){
              alert( "account creation "+ content.message)

              window.location.href='/'
 
    
            }else{
              alert("register failed user already registered")
            }


          }else{
            alert('password missmatch')
          }
           }else{
             alert('password must me different with username')
           }

          }else{
            alert("please choose a password with min. 6 letters")
          }

        }else{
          alert("please choose a username with min. 6 letters")
        }

        }

  </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

my posts.js:

```
const express= require('express');
const router=express();
const bcrypt= require('bcrypt');
const Post=require('../model/post');
router.use(express.json());

'message'
router.post('/users/new', (req,res)=> {

    console.log("bin in posts")
    alert("bin in posts")
    Post.find({username: req.body.username})
        .exec()
        .then(users =>{
            if(users.length >= 1){
                return res.status(409).json({
                    message:"username already used"
                });
            }
            else{
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err,hash){
                    if(err){
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            error:err
                        })
                    }
                    else{
                        
                    
                    
                        const user= new Post({
                            username: req.body.username,
                            password: hash
                        })
                        
                        user.save()
                     
                            
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                message:'success',
                              
                            })
                    }
                })
            }
        })

})
module.exports=router;
```

when i try to access my fetch with **172.21.101.196:30286** im still getting : register:75          POST https://172.21.101.196:4000/users/new net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

is the adress wrong? am i taking a wrong adress? on my docker-compose version it works with localhost, so the code cant be wrong

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I am guessing that `user.save()` is where the MongoDB write is meant to happen. It looks as though `user.save()` is never returning.